# How can I put a SCSI request in the queue in Linux Kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, scsi

I try to create a Linux kernel module that filters SCSI requests. The idea is very simple: I enumerate all Scsi_hosts by calling the function `scsi_host_lookup()` and modify the corresponding pointers

```
host->hostt->queuecommand.
```

This hooking works.

However,  I need to do some complicated work during the dispatching scsi requests. I can't do it immediately in my hook function since it is called in the context that doesn't support interrupts.

I've already tried the following approach: I created a work queue, and in my hook function I put scsi requests into this queue and then returned zero. In the work queue functions I called original  `host->hostt->queuecommand` functions.  The system didn't crash but it was stuck. I think that it resulted because I returned constantly zeros in my hook function.

Could you help me with it?